# What if bindip is deleted in mongod.conf

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, security

My application got attacked by Ransomware, my DB(Mongodb 3.0)  is on private vpc, still they are able to hack it.

I have following query

1. what if bind_ip is commented in mongod.conf. Can it be connected from outside? As per documentation default is 127.0.0.1.
2. How private VPC on AWS can be accessed from outside? My AWS instance for mongo is on private not public, only application is pubic.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible so how we can access to you mongodb..
**we can enable it**

**1 - MongoDB server**

- Private IP – 192.168.161.100
- Public IP – 45.56.65.100
- MongoDB 2.6.3, port 27017
- IpTables Firewall

MongoDB doesn’t allow remote connections.

**1 - Bind IP**

```
$ vim /etc/mongod.conf

# /etc/mongod.conf

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

you know MongoDB automatically bind to local interface only, it'll restrict the remote connection.
if your security is not important for you just you can accept any connection **And I should tell you this is not RECOMMENDED**

if you can not grasp this words please click the link below : 
[all Information](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/)

Please read this article for your security

Best regards

Comment: I know these details but my scenario is no public IP for mongo instance, only private ip. bind_ip is commented so I consider it as bind_ip = 127.0.0.1.  Is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation.

1. if your bind_ip is 0.0.0.0 then it can be accessed from other machine in network not when bind_ip is 127.0.0.1 (It is Ok if your bindIp is commented.)
2. To save yourself from such attacks, You should give username and password to your mongoDB.

Do give username password ASAP so that it won't happen again.
It will definitely save your database. It's recommended too.

Comment: #1. 0.0.0.0 can be accessed from other machine, but if bind_ip is commented, still it can be?

Comment: @sanjeev - but if it has username password then how can it be accessed ?

Comment: It dont have username and password, but we had it for private connection only.